# NSNotification userinfo example?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have an array of objects that are positioned using CGPoints . At certain times in my app, an object in the array needs to notify other non-arrayed objects of its position. I understand that NSNotification is the best way to go, but I cant find a decent example of a 'sender' and 'reciever' for the notification that wraps and unwraps a CGPoint as userinfo. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Cocoa Touch (but not Cocoa), CGPoints can be wrapped and unwrapped with

```
+ (NSValue *)valueWithCGPoint:(CGPoint)point
- (CGPoint)CGPointValue
```

NSValues can be stored in the NSDictionary passed as the userinfo parameter.

For example:

```
NSValue* value = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:mypoint];
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:@"mypoint"];
```

And in your notification:

```
NSValue* value = [dict objectForKey:@"mypoint"];
CGPoint newpoint = [value CGPointValue];
```

Comment: In Cocoa, you can use NSPointFromCGPoint, then use NSValue's valueWithPoint: and pointValue.

Comment: Or you can build with NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64 predefined, in which case NSPoint is a typedef for CGPoint (it always is in 64-bit builds).

Answer (score 1):

The userinfo object passed along with the notification is simply an NSDictionary. Probably easiest way of passing a CGPoint in the userinfo would be to wrap up the X and Y coordinates into NSNumbers using -numberWithFloat:. You can then use setObject:forKey: on the userinfo dictionary using Xpos and Ypos as the keys for example.

You could probably wrap that up into a nice category on NSMutableDictionary, with methods like setFloat:forKey or something...